# More questions about generalised cartesian product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**After seeing similar questions on stackexchange, it araise me with new questions.**

I am fine with the notation of cartesian product viewing as the ordered list like this:

**[Definition1]** let $\{X_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets, $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}:=\{(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})|\forall i\in I, x_{i}\in X_{i}\}.  $$

When you look this as a collection of functions, the every detail of definiton is as followed. 
**[Definition2]**

$$\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_{i}=\{f:I\rightarrow\bigcup X_{i}|\:\forall i\in I,\:f(i)\in X_{i}\} \text{[definition 2]}$$

Below are my questions

Just look at this part from **[Definition2]**$\{f:I\rightarrow \bigcup X_i|\:\forall i\in I,f(x_i)\in X_i\}$, I don't think this is the set of ordered list from codomain, but just a simple set $\bigcup X_{i}$ whose elements are $x_i$ only. **[May need more comments here]**

In case of my bad english cannot makes you know what I am really asking for, here is the attached from John hunter's note

> > [image]

**Q1**:From my understanding, he was trying to bend his definition exactly the same as the **[Definition1]**. if $x_i=f(i)$ has already defined (e.g output of $f \:\text{is just a}\: x_i \in X_i$,  how come the output of $f$ turns out to be an ordered n-tuple.

I find another concrete example below illustrates the **[definition2]** perfectly, but I have no idea how to bridge this example with **[definition1]**.

**Q2** How to fit the idea that element of $\prod X_i$ is a set $\{(0,a),(1,c)\} $ from **[definition2]** with element $(a,c) \in \prod X_i$ from  **[Definition1]**

> > [image]

$\large \text{Question End}$

$\large \text{Below are my original post}$

However, after reading others explaination in concrete example as $I=\{1,2\}$, I find that  [definition 2] actually is saying that $\prod\limits_{i\in I}X_{i}=\{f:I\rightarrow\bigcup X_{i} \text{ given by} f:=(f(1),f(2)) |\forall f(1)\in X_{1}, f(2)\in X_2\} $. Then why does not the original [definition2] add on extra information $f:=(f(i)_{\forall i \in I})$, if so, it turns out to be indifferent to [definition1].

The others explaination is attached.

> > [image]

Any comments and feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Definition 1 makes no sense, what is $n$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila re-editted

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer the question. Where did $n$ come from?

Comment: @AsafKaragila just an arbitrary number that i could takes

Comment: And why is it finite?

Comment: @AsafKaragila just a assumption

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the point where using the generalised definition is *better*, when $I$ is infinite Definition 2 is fine, whereas the definition of a tuple breaks down and we fall back to simply a function (so we get to Definition 2 in the case of Definition 1 as well).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you please comment more on how tuples break down to a functions, or would you please show me how to link tuples with function in finite sets. (e.g  in above concrete example that I provided). Cheers

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325778/a-question-on-the-generalization-of-cartesian-product https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332534/understanding-the-definition-of-product-of-sets and also maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353946/is-bbb-r-different-from-bbb-r%e2%81%bf-where-n-1-in-that-bbb-r-is-not-a-s  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744675/what-is-the-difference-between-bbbrn-times-bbbrm-and-bbbrmn and there might be quite a few more. You said you've looked at other questions, but you may have missed those.

Comment: Please don't add the set-theory tag. It does not belong here.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sorry to bother. Not sure where it belongs to?

Comment: The tag description indicates this.

Answer (score 1):

First, when we write "$X_i$ for (each) $i\in I$", we are assuming that we have a function $g$ with domain $I,$ but we are writing $X_i$ for $g(i).$

Second, the members of $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ are the functions from $I$ into $\cup_{i\in I}X_i=\cup_{i\in I}\,g(i)$ (not into some disjoint union) that satisfy $\forall i\in I\,(f(i)\in g(i)).$

Example. Let $I=\Bbb N$ and $g(i)=X_i=\{0,1\}$  for each $i\in I.$ Then $\bigcup \{X_i:i\in I\}=\cup_{i\in I}g(i)=\{0,1\}.$ In this example, any $f:I\to \{0,1\}$ will automatically satisfy $\forall i\in I\,(f(i)\in X_i)$.... and $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is the set of all $f:\Bbb N\to \{0,1\}.$ This product-set is often denoted by $^{\Bbb N}\{0,1\}$ or $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ or $2^{\Bbb N}.$

Example. For $r\in \Bbb R$ let $X_r=(-\infty,r].$ Then $\prod_{r\in \Bbb R}X_r$ is the set of all $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that satisfy $\forall r\in \Bbb R\,(f(r)\le r).$

When $I$ is finite there is usually more than one def'n available in set theory for $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ but the different resulting sets are isomorphic in a  natural way so we usually take a def'n which is convenient for a given context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you please shed more lights on that the set of all $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ would be $\mathbb N$ fold of $\{0,1\}$